# Swift compiler error: “Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'”

Tags: ios, swift, higher-order-functions

I have a range that I'm trying to map on, but I'm getting the error

`“Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'”`

Here's what the code looks like

```
    let patterns = (0...5).map { verseNum in
        let verseNumberStartPattern = "\"verse-num\">\(verseNum)</span>(?:\\s?<span>)?(.*?)<"
        let chapterStartPattern = "\"chapter-num\">\\s\(parsedVerse.chapterStart)\\s</span>"
        if verseNum == 1 {
            return chapterStartPattern + "(.*?)<"
        } else {
            return chapterStartPattern + "(?:.*?)" + verseNumberStartPattern
        }
    }
```

If I take out everything inside the closure and just return "", then the compiler doesn't complain. However, even if I add one line other than the return empty string, then the compiler complains, such as for:

```
    let patterns = (0...5).map { verseNum in
        let verseNumberStartPattern = "\"verse-num\">\(verseNum)</span>(?:\\s?<span>)?(.*?)<"
        return ""
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Swift can't infer types from the context every time. If it can't infer types, you have to type them explicitly, in this case the return type:

```
let patterns = (0...5).map { verseNum -> String in
```

In this case I believe Swift should be able to infer the type so it might be a bug.

Comment: I would add that this really is a bug in Swift’s type inference, rather than a way it _has_ to be.  `verseNum` should be inferable from the range, and the return value from the return statements.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have a subclass, you'll need to use the base class type name, then ask for the object again "as!" your subclass.

Comment: This happened to me with the following code, still puzzled Swift cannot infer the type of the String constructor when using format.

Not working code:
`(0...23).map { String(format: "%02d", $0) }`

Working code:
`(0...23).map { hour -> String in String(format: "%02d", hour) }`